# How can I prevent others to see my files in github?

Tags: github

I have web files in github. All of them are downloadable by anyone. But I want to prevent this download from other. How can it be possible?

Answer (score 1):

Github offers the possibility to private repositories but this feature is not for free. You have many other git providers offering private repositories for free.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a paid account. Then you are able to define your repository as private.

Answer (score 0):

If you're learning at school or you're a student you could join to GitHub Student Developer Pack (https://education.github.com/pack). This package has a lot of interesting tools, including private GitHub repositories, until you're at school or university. Just send a photo of your student card /school ID and give information when it's valid.